# Reading SharedPreferences stored by Activity in a Service?

Tags: android, android-activity, service, sharedpreferences, storage

I am using a class to create a background service which runs all the time. When using the Android app the user can enter data which are stored via SharedPreferences. The storing works well and the stored data are available in the activity which stores it. I am using SharedPreferences like this:

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("Identifier",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

In the service I am trying to access to this values that are stored in the activity. Therefore I am using the SharedPreferences the same way:

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("Identifier",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

I am storing an object this way in the activity:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
String json = gson.toJson(myObject);
prefsEditor.putString("value",json);
prefsEditor.commit();
```

And try to read it this way, but json returns null:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = mPrefs.getString("value",null);
```

Any idea what might be wrong? Is the context wrong? But how should it be?

Comment: Have you verified that 'String json = gson.toJson(myObject);' is not null before saving? Maybe you have some conflict in your object.

Comment: Yes, checked it. It works. After storing, I am reloading the activity and the stored value is successfully loaded in the activity.

Comment: Ok, use applicationContext.getSharedPreferences

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a default shared preferences instance, which is shared across all your Activity and Service classes, use below method.

```
SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this/*context*/);
```

This is the best way for storing primitives datatype(like booleans) or serializable objects. However, if you're capturing a lot of JSON data, you might consider using an SQLite database instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the service is running in a different process. Therefore I used tray which works perfectly for multiple processes: https://github.com/grandcentrix/tray.